# How to create file names with changing number

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to save images in number.jpg for each time.

For example, first I will save it as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ...

I will be writing the images using `imwrite()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should really have researched this a little more but making numbered filenames is very easy:

```
int filecount = 0; //increment this

stringstream filename;
filename << "filename_" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << filecount << ".jpg";
```

`setfill` and `setw` make the width of the number 4 and ill it out with 0 so it will look like:

```
filename_0000.jpg
filename_0001.jpg
...
```

You can then use imwrite like this:

```
imwrite(filename.str().c_str(), image);
```

Comment: thx a lot! I just didn't know what stringstream is. Anyway thx!

Comment: @user3531608 not a problem, i remember being new to c++, and still sort of am. There is a lot to learn.